# No Until date in USA admit stamp B1/B2

Tags: usa, passport-stamps, i-94

My USA entry stamp for B1/B2 only has admit date but the officer forgot to stamp or write Until date. How long can I stay in USA or do i need to reach out to anyone so  I can stay in USA legally for 6 months

Answer (score 35):

Your first step should be to look up your electronic record at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/. That will usually tell you how long you've been admitted for.

Comment: If you have multiple passports or a visa in your old passport, use the passport number with the visa while searching as the website tags the entry against the passport which contains the visa (even if the passport has expired) and not always the latest passport